# Is it possible to password protect the cloning of a repo on github?

Tags: github

I'm trying to create a more secure development environment by disabling the cloning of repositores without my knowledge. I mostly use freelancers.

Is it possible to password protect the cloning of a private repository on GitHub?

In other words, before one of the collaborators clone the code, they would need to enter a password.

Thanks for the help

Comment: People will always be able to clone a local clone of your repo by accessing the filesystem directly.

Comment: You can only make your repository private, in other cases, i.e. when the repo is public, all people are able to clone yuor repository freely.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to do this

1. If its github or a public repository (assuming your repository is private) - you can only allow authorise .SSH keys
2. As your rightly said via passwords - freelancers create their account on GitHub/Bitbucket. You then authorise those accounts to clone

When the work has been completed, you can revoke privileges to the account and the .SSH public keys.

Whilst this is not for discussion on stackoverflow. If you are worried about the code being leaked - standard contracts that confirms that the entity (who hired the freelancer) owns all code produced and NDA (Non-Disclosure Agreement).